# How to convert a json string into an individual character array in bash?

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I have a json string that I need to convert into an array for passing a password in.  Current issue is I need to do this for many users

Current json looks like this which was generated from

```
[
   {
        "password": "Password1",
        "loginId": "USER1"
   }
]
```

I need to change it to this

```
[ 
   { 
      "password":[ 
         "P",
         "a",
         "s",
         "s",
         "w",
         "o",
         "r",
         "d",
         "1"
      ],
      "loginId":"USER1"
   }
]
```

I'd prefer to do this in bash but if anyone has other options I'm open to anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), splitting a string by empty string results in a character array just as you need.

```
jq '.[].password |= split("")' file
```

[Online demo at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/t3q415lHCF)

Comment: Wow that was super simple.  Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

With [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) you can use the XPath/XQuery function [`x:cps()`](http://www.benibela.de/documentation/internettools/xpath-functions.html#x-cps) twice to turn the string into an array and [`map:put()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-map-put) to update the JSON.

```
xidel -s input.json -e '[$json()/map:put(.,"password",x:cps(x:cps(password)))]'
[
  {
    "password": [
      "P",
      "a",
      "s",
      "s",
      "w",
      "o",
      "r",
      "d",
      "1"
    ],
    "loginId": "USER1"
  }
]
```

[Online xidelcgi demo](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/xidelcgi?&data=%5B%0A%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22password%22%3A%20%22Password1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22loginId%22%3A%20%22USER1%22%0A%20%20%7D%0A%5D&=&extract=%5B%24json()%2Fmap%3Aput(.%2C%22password%22%2Cx%3Acps(x%3Acps(password)))%5D&=&input-format=auto&printed-node-format=text&output-format=adhoc&compatibility=Enable%20all%20extensions&dot-notation=unambiguous&extract-kind=auto).

Comment: Seems like an excellent tool, wonder why I have never heard about it

Answer (score 0):

Handling JSON through Bash is a bad idea. Awk is not better at all but it can be done :

```
awk -F':' '
function ltrim(s) { sub(/^[ \t\r\n]+/, "", s); return s }
function rtrim(s) { sub(/[ \t\r\n]+$/, "", s); return s }
function trim(s) { return rtrim(ltrim(s)); }
!/"password"/ {
    print $0
}
/"password"/ {
    found=1;
    print $1 ":["
    password = $2
    gsub(/"|,/, " ", password)
    split(trim(password),letters,"")
    for(c=1; c <= length(letters); c++ ) {
        printf("\t\t\"%s\"",letters[c])
        if (c != length(letters)) {
            printf(",\n")
        }else{
            printf("\n\t\t]\n")
        }
    }
}
' input.txt
```

On the other hand. I think the right tool for this is Python 3 actually :

```
python3 -c '
import json

result = []

list = json.loads("""
[
   {
        "password": "Password1",
        "loginId": "USER1"
   }
]
""")
for item in list:
  result.append({ "loginId" : item["loginId"], "password" : [char for char in item["password"]] })

print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
'
```

Hope this helps!